# DataScroller do primefaces só carrega apenas uma vez com lazy

Tags: primefaces, hibernate, jsf-2.2, jpa, primefaces-3.5

Gente, comecei a usar hoje o dataScroller com lazy do primefaces

```
<p:dataScroller  ajax="true" id="listaDiarios" 
    chunkSize="3"  lazy="true"
    styleClass='ui-datagrid-no-border'
    value="#{managedBeanUsuario.lazyRegistrosDiarios}"
    var="registro">
```

O load fiz da seguinte forma:

```
LazyDataModel<RegistroDiario> registros = new LazyDataModel<RegistroDiario>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4742720028771554420L;
   @Override
public List<RegistroDiario> load(int first, int pageSize,
        String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
        Map<String, Object> filters) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       System.out.println("entrei load "+ first);
       System.out.println("entrei size "+ pageSize); 
       System.out.println("qnt linhas "+ this.getRowCount()); 

         return RegistroDiarioDao.getAllLastRegistroDiarioVelho(first);

}
};
```

E na DAO o método está assim:

```
public static ArrayList<RegistroDiario> getAllLastRegistroDiarioVelho(int inicio) {

    EntityManager em = HibernateManageFactory.getFactory() 
            .createEntityManager();

    Query query = em.createQuery(
            "select u from RegistroDiario u order by u.dtRegistro desc",
            RegistroDiario.class);
    query.setMaxResults(3); 
    query.setFirstResult(inicio);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    ArrayList<RegistroDiario> registrosDiarios = (ArrayList<RegistroDiario>) query.getResultList();

    em.close();
    return registrosDiarios;
}
```

Ele trás os registros, até ai tudo bem.

Eu quero que ele traga sempre de 3 em 3, na primeira vez ele trás 3, quando desse o a barra de rolagem, ele trás mais 3 e depois ele para de ir buscar mais registros. Sendo que eu tenho muito mais que 6 registros no banco.

Não sei se estou fazendo certo ou errado, por isso queria a ajuda de vocês, quero que ele traga todos os registros do banco, porém indo buscando de 3 em 3